# How to set initial_balance such that when we deposit amount it gets added to the balance_amount

Tags: python

> Example: If initial_balance = 0 and if we add some amount say 10000 then balance shows 10000, but when we again deposit amount say 5000 then it should show balance 15000, but it's showing the newly deposited amount as 5000 and that it's not getting added to the existing balance. How to set that it gets added to the existing balance.

Please help me. I'm not able to figure out how to set it so.

```
class Bank:
def deposit():
    pass

class Customer(Bank):
def data(self):
    action = input('What do you want to do Deposit or Withdrawl? ')
    if action in ['deposit', 'withdrawl']:
        if action == 'deposit':
            dep_amount = input('Enter the amount you want to deposit ')
            initial_balance = 0
            try:
                dep_amount = int(dep_amount)
                print(f'{dep_amount}/- has been deposited. You can check the transaction file for statement')
                balance_amount = initial_balance + dep_amount
                with open('Deposits', 'a') as depFile:
                    depFile.write('\n')
                    depFile.write(str(balance_amount))
            except ValueError:
                dep_amount = 'Not a an amount'
                print(dep_amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run the code you are setting `initial_balance` to 0. So the,`balance_amount = 0 + dep_amount` .

```
dep_amount = input('Enter the amount you want to deposit ')
initial_balance = 0

try:
   dep_amount = int(dep_amount)
   .....
   balance_amount = initial_balance + dep_amount
      
except ValueError:
   .....
```

So you need to save the balance in somewhere else staticly and retrieve
it when you call the function.